# Function Return Value Not Updating

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with multiple sheets and I am trying to run a test function to return a cell value that gets updated based on values from a different sheet.
Here is my basic function which simply returns a value from an array:

```
Function test(t2)
    Application.Volatile
    Dim costArray As Variant
    costArray = Array(Range("W34"), Range("W35"), Range("W36"))
    test = costArray(1)
End Function
```

This properly returns the correct value, but when I update a dependency cell value from the different sheet, the return value gets set to 0 and I have to manually refresh the function to get the updated value. As you can see, I have tried to use the Application.Volatile method, but does not seem to help.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Public Function TestMe(ParamArray costArray() As Variant) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    TestMe = costArray(1)
End Function
```

I guess that the `Application.Volatile` concerns only the parameters. Thus, give the three parameters as a range.

> The `ParamArray` specifies that a procedure parameter takes an optional array of elements of the specified type. ParamArray can be used only on the last parameter of a parameter list.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/paramarray

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @RobertS - welcome, I have edited it to something a bit better- the `ParamArray()`